# 8 - How do I load a Term entity from an EntityReferenceItem?

Tags: entities, 8

I have a content type with a taxonomy term. I can load the first `EntityReferenceItem` using

`$node->country->get(0)`

then I can `tid` doing `->target_id` (and then manually load the Term object via `Term::load`.

But is there a function of EntityReferenceItem that I can call to get it to load the corresponding term? I'm thinking something like:

```
  $node->country->get(0)->getReferenced()
```

I don't see anything at the [Drupal API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21EntityReferenceItem.php/class/EntityReferenceItem/8.2.x)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$node->country->entity.
```

See http://wizzlern.nl/drupal/drupal-8-entity-cheat-sheet, where it lists the properties of common field types.

If you want to see the properties of a field type, one way to do that is by looking at the propertyDefinitions() method of the field type class, in this case EntityReferenceItem.

Comment: What is there multiple values allowed? ->country[0]->entity ?

Comment: not specifying a delta means [0],works always, also on multi-value fields. Delta works with [1] or ->get(1).

Answer (score 0):

Update code for 8.6, following example of term reference field

```
$tid = $para->get('field_category')->getString();
$tname = $para->get('field_category')
      ->get(0)
      ->get('entity')
      ->getString();
```